# Raising socket.error from client to server

Tags: python

I've the following problem. I've a Server Application that accepts sockets connections wrapped over SSL. The client sends user and password over it, once on the Server I check if the user/password is correct.

If the user/password is wrong I want the Server to send to the Client a Socket.error. Right now the only idea that comes to mind is sending back to the client "Wrong Password" but I think it is safer to use the built-in errors, this way I can warp the code over a try except statement.

Is it there anyway to send a socket error from the Server to the Client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest method would be to send back some sort of return code and when the client sees the return code from the server, it would throw the exception itself.

Comment: In fact, how are you telling the client they're authenticated in the first place if you don't have some sort of acknowledgement?

Comment: It is a bit more complex than just that. Right now I have the SSL connection to be sure that the connection will be safe, that is with a Certificate, I know the user will be a trusted user, but I need to check that the user is who he/she says to be, that is why I need the second check, the reason behind this is that then I create a new channel for ZeroMQ. The certificate is public, everyone with that application will have it, because we cannot create one for every user (we will have up to 1600 users using that application)

Comment: It sounds like a normal authentication setup, unless I'm mis-understanding. You can't send a socket error to a client, as it's language specific, unless you mean you want to close the socket forcefully, which would generate an error if the client tried to read from it. But to do it more gracefully, you should be sending some sort of acknowledgement to the client stating that they're authenticated or not, if the server comes back and says they're not authenticated you can throw whatever error you want (including socket.error) to clean up.

Comment: "You can't send a socket error to a client" <--- This is exactly what I wanted to know! I guess I will follow your advice and send my own code to the client and then Raise the exception at it. Thanks